# Get pointers for values in the slice

Tags: go

Is there any way to get pointers to the actual value in slice? I have a tree of offers in the maps:

```
map[uint64]map[uint16][]offer
```

For fast access by id (which from 1 to n) I need a slice of pointers:

```golang
[]*offer
```

Actual offers lies in the first tree, in the slice should be pointers to the that actual.

I can't traverse tree and collect pointers of actual values because with `range` of this slice gives me a copies, but I have more than billions of this structs in total and copies will lead to waste of my memory: 40 bytes for one struct lead to the 100+ gb and much more in the future. I also need to store slice of values in the tree to contiguous in order to fact lookup of offers.

May be there are some way to use `unsafe` or `reflect` package to get these pointers?

Index of pointers build only one time and both structs are immutable and only used to lookup offers.

**Update:**
I was totally wrong. There is no problem to get pointer to element in the slice. My code was:

```
        var offers []offer // actually there was about 50gb of offers
        for i := range offers {
            currentOffer := offers[i]
            s.Relations[currentOffer.Id] = &currentOffer
        }
```

After this snippet overall amount of ram consumed by the app became 100+gb. I immediately thought that take element from slice of values give me a copy of that value, but it is wrong. I just copied original value to the `currentOffer` variable by myself. Little mistake took 50gb of ram away.

Actually this snippet is work fine as expected:

```
    for i := range offers {
        s.Relations[offers[i].Id] = &offers[i]
    }
```

Comment: It isn't clear how and what you store in your map of maps. But if you need fast lookup of offers by id, why don't you store that in the first place? `map[uint64][]*offer`?

Comment: Something like this https://play.golang.com/p/gxLX6oo8hAP ?

Comment: @icza i need two indexes, one for two keys (uint64 and uint16 in this case) and second by id of offer. There should be only one copy of offer. Second index should be as pointer to the original offer.

Comment: @mkopriva your script copy offer struct when you access by index. In my case it doubles amount of memory for offers which without doubling is already 50+ gb.

Comment: You could store your offers in a flat array, and then all your indexes can be pointers to elements in this array. No need for any shenanigans with reflect or unsafe.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev store actual values in the main index gives me more performance for retrieving bucket of offers instead of collecting it from the sparse heap memory in case of storing pointers.

Comment: @abonec: with billions of elements, I don't doubt.

Comment: it seems like you answered your own question. You can update your answer to include the correct solution.

Answer (score -2):

After some investigation I came to the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

type offer struct {
    id uint64
}

func main() {

    sl := []offer{{1}, {id: 2}}

    size := unsafe.Sizeof(offer{})
    header := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&sl))
    for i := 0; i < len(sl); i++ {
        offset := uintptr(i) * size
        ptr := header.Data + offset

        o := (*offer)(unsafe.Pointer(ptr))
        o.id = 5
        fmt.Println(o)
    }

    for _, o := range sl {
        fmt.Println(o.id)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/OM3i84cKAB_7

Output:

```
&{5}
&{5}
5
5
```

This snippet of code illustrate access to the actual data in the slice, not copied one.

**Update:**
Take pointers via unsafe pointer give the same effect as take regular pointer from the slice by index.

Comment: In terms of changing slice values is no difference, but I showed how to do it by the reference to this value. In my case I need a reference to the value, not the copy.

Comment: @abonec: note the warning that `go vet` gives you here, you really shouldn't ever need to do pointer arithmetic in Go.